# Try to do something similar to @Adjust in jsp

Tags: java, date, jsp, jstl, jstl-functions

I am trying to determine whether the date is within 60 days (compare to today's date).

If the service date is within 60 days, the column will show "Yes", on the other hand, if the date is over 60 days, the column will show "No".

I know if in lotus notes application, I can use this formula to achieve it

```
@If(@Adjust(ServiceDate; 0; ; 60; 0; 0; 0) >= @Today; "Yes"; "No")
```

Now, I try to do something similar in the jsp file (no lotus notes application)

```
 <display:table name="${serviceList}" class="its" uid="row"
        sort="list" pagesize="10" requestURI="service_view" export="false" defaultsort="2" defaultorder="descending" id="serviceTable">

    <display:column style="width: 30%" title="Service Name" property="serviceName"  />

    <!-- this column is for display -->
    <display:column style="width: 10%" title="Service Date" property="serviceDate" format="{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy}" />

    <!-- this service date is for calculation -->
    <display:column title="Service date">

    <fmt:formatDate value="${attr.row.serviceDate}" var="formatservicedate" 
            type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
    <c:set var= "servicedate" value = "${formatservicedate}" /> 
    <c:out value = "${servicedate}" />
    </display:column>

    <!-- this today's date is for calculation -->
    <display:column title='today date'>  

     <%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat, java.util.Calendar, java.text.DateFormat"%>
     <%
         DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
         Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();           
     %>

    <%-- try to use variable to show --%>
    <!-- get today's date in dd/mm/yyyy by variable -->

    <c:set var= "todaydate" value = "<%=    dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) %>" />
    <c:out value = "${todaydate}" />
    </display:column>

    <display:column title='Is within 60 days'>
        <%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat, java.util.Calendar, java.text.DateFormat"%>
     <%
         DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
         Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();           
     %>

       <!-- get today's date in dd/mm/yyyy by variable -->
    <c:set var= "todaydate" value = "<%=    dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) %>" />

    <!-- get service date by variable-->
    <fmt:formatDate value="${attr.row.serviceDate}" var="formatservicedate" 
            type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    <c:set var= "servicedate" value = "${formatservicedate}" /> 

    <!-- I tried <c:if test="${servicedate + 60 ge todaydate}"> but not work -->
    <!-- I am not sure how to plus 60 days for service date in the logic -->
    <c:if test="${servicedate ge todaydate}">
     <p><b>Yes</b></p>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${!servicedate ge todaydate}">
     <p><b>No</b></p>
    </c:if>

    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

So I would like to know is it possible to do something similar to @Adjust() in jsp to determine the date is within 60 days? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am thinking about add 60 days to service date first, and then use it to compare today's date. If the date is >= today's date, the column will show "Yes" otherwise the column will show "No". Do I missed something in this logic?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure it out.

First get today's date and service's date by variable.

Then prepare the logic

Find out equation for a day

```
60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours
```

Find equation for days

```
Math.abs(variable1.getTime() - variable2.getTime());
```

If days divide a day <=60, show yes,else show no